# Replacing commands.getoutput with subprocess

Tags: python, replace, subprocess

I am struggling to replace commands.getoutput with subprocess.
Please see the codes below:

```
import subprocess
import commands
dir = subprocess.check_output(['pwd'])
print dir+"/*.py"
dir = commands.getoutput('pwd')
print dir+"/*.py"
```

Here's the ouput:

```
/home/akik/py
/*.py

/home/akik/py/*.py
```

Please help me fixing it.

Answer (score 1):

`getoutput()` strips the newline printed by `pwd` command. You have to do it manually with `check_output()`:

```
from subprocess import check_output

dirname = check_output(['pwd']).rstrip("\n")
print dirname + "/*.py"
```